# Very stumped! CSS Contact Form animation won't work on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, transition, contact-form

Please bear with me. This is my first question & I'm not an expert, nor do I have an iOS device to regularly use for testing.

I incorporated this CSS Contact Form I found on a free tutorial page for our wedding website as my fiance loved it. It works great on my Desktop PC and Android devices but but when I had a friend test it on his iPhone 6+ (Safari & Chrome), I found that it doesn't work. On iOS, the envelope image loads up but there is no transition on hover or click. I also had it tested on an iPhone 5 (Safari) with the same result.

I have spent the past week trying to solve it, including trying many of the proposed issues & suggestions I found on SO. Some of them were as follows:

> SUGGESTED ISSUE: `:hover` doesn't work on iOS
>   SOLUTION 1: Use `:active` and/or `:focus` to every instance that uses :hover
>   SOLUTION 2: Add `cursor:pointer` to the CSS element or div
>   SOLUTION 3: Change the body tag to `<body ontouchstart="">`
>   SOLUTION 4: Add `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);`

I don't even know if the `:hover` issue still exists with iOS as most of the SO pages that mentioned that issue were over a year old. After experimenting with a mix-match of the above suggested solutions, I found that SOLUTION 3 or SOLUTION 4 got the transition to work on iOS but with several glitches:

> GLITCH 1: When the page first loads, the transition won't work unless you actually touch AND hold your finger on the envelope. The second you take your finger off the screen, the form slides back down.
>   GLITCH 2: If you zoom the screen in a little bit, the transition seems to work properly (single tap or touch to trigger transition). However, if the page is viewed in landscape, it goes back to having to touch and hold for the transition to work.
>   GLITCH 3: If you zoom the screen in even further, the form automatically pops out of the envelope instantly with no transition...regardless of a touch, tap or long press.

What is causing it to not work on iOS? 
How would I go about correcting this issue?

It's been a frustrating week but I don't want to give up and am humbly requesting any help/explanations from anyone. And I apologize for the long question. I was trying to follow the posting rules and also offer enough detail to help find a solution. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the  [link to the working demo.](http://pehaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/contactform/contactform.html) (Mouse-over on PC or touch top of envelope on Android)
Here is the  [link to the tutorial page for this demo.](http://pehaa.com/2011/07/create-a-unique-contact-form-with-css3-transitions/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <script  src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]><script>
    $(document).ready(function() {     
$("#form_wrap").addClass('hide');    
})    
</script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h1>Send a message</h1>
        <div id='form_wrap'>
            <form>
                <p>Hello Joe,</p>
                <label for="email">Your Message : </label>
                <textarea  name="message" value="Your Message" id="message" ></textarea>
                <p>Best,</p>    
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
                <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Now, I send, thanks!" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, div, h1,h2, form, fieldset, input, textarea, footer,p {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border: 0; 
    outline: none;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';
    src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.svg#YanoneKaffeesatzRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    background: #ccc url('images/bg_out.png'); 
    color: #7c7873; 
    font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';
}
p {
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff; 
    font-size:24px;
}
#wrap {
    width:530px; 
    margin:20px auto 0; 
    height:1000px;
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:48px; 
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ede8d9; 
}
#form_wrap { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    height:446px; 
    position:relative; 
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
}   
#form_wrap:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:128px;
    left:0px;
    background:url('images/before.png');
    width:530px;
    height: 316px;
}   
#form_wrap:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    background:url('images/after.png');
    width:530px;
    height: 260px; 
}
#form_wrap.hide:after, #form_wrap.hide:before {
    display:none; 
}
#form_wrap:hover {
    height:776px;
    top:-200px;
}
form {
    background:#f7f2ec url('images/letter_bg.png'); 
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:20px; 
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 14px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
}
#form_wrap:hover form {
    height:530px;
}
label {
    margin: 11px 20px 0 0; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #b3aba1;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
input[type=text], textarea {
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
    color: #7c7873;
    background:none;
    width: 380px; 
    height: 36px; 
    padding: 0px 10px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border:1px solid #f8f5f1;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #726959;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895; 
    box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895;
}   
textarea { 
    height: 80px; 
    padding-top:14px;
}
textarea:focus, input[type=text]:focus {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.35);
}
#form_wrap input[type=submit] {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular'; 
    font-size:24px; 
    color: #7c7873;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;
    background:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#form_wrap:hover input[type=submit] {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
}
#form_wrap:hover input:hover[type=submit] {
    color:#435c70;
}
```

Comment: From the same author, a bit different: http://dabblet.com/gist/4065578. I don't know exactly what is going wrong, but if you are going to copy a form, you can copy this: it works on every single device.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Siyah. I just played around with the form you suggested and I really like the flip animation but I still prefer other form for a few reasons. 1) The style of the hover envelope fits in better with the theme of our wedding site. 2) Each time you click the "flip", "open" or "close" buttons on the flip style envelope, it adds a page in your browser's history, meaning that if you flipped the envelope 4 times, you have to click the back button 4 times to go back to where you were.